# MySQL getting duplicates from select distinct + union

Tags: mysql

When I run the following query in MySQL I get lots of duplicates. I know I've been more than clear enough that I just need distinct records, so I can't understand why it would double it up for me. It seems that all duplicates appears when I include the last union(`importorders` table) since most customers have the same address in customers and orders. Can anyone help me understand why this happends?

```
SELECT DISTINCT PostalCode, City, Region, Country
FROM 
(select distinct postalcode, city, region, country
from importemployees
UNION
select distinct postalcode, city, region, country
from importcustomers
UNION
select distinct postalcode, city, region, country
from importproducts
UNION
select distinct shippostalcode as postalcode, shipcity as city, shipregion as region, shipcountry as country
from importorders) T
```

---

[image: Query and result]

As you can see. Some rows are duplicates.

If I use `INSERT IGNORE` to insert `importcustomers` first, then `importorders`, then it manages to identify the records as duplicates. Why doesn't the select-query work?

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate? Column or Whole row?

Comment: I mean duplicate rows. Values looks identical in the identical rows. Can ex. different charset/collation in the tables(or when imported from csv) trigger this?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this. Can you post a live [sql-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) for this?

Comment: better yet. I got the export from MySQL workbench. I just imported it and tried some queries like the one above. Don't know where the error is, so if you could use it all. School assignment, so nothing confidential =)  http://www.ge.tt/69lmmZN/v/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very curious problem. When I drop 'Country' it seems to solve the issue.

```
SELECT DISTINCT PostalCode, City, Region
```

*128 total, Query took 0.0066 sec*

```
SELECT DISTINCT PostalCode, City, Region, Country
```

*209 total, Query took 0.0002 sec*

Further, the behavior seems to only be affecting `ImportCustomers` and `ImportOrders`:

```
SELECT postalcode, city, region, country
FROM 
    (SELECT postalcode, city, region, country FROM importcustomers
    UNION
    SELECT shippostalcode, shipcity, shipregion, shipcountry FROM importorders) t
```

*172 total, Query took 0.0053 sec*

```
SELECT postalcode
FROM 
    (SELECT postalcode FROM importcustomers
    UNION
    SELECT shippostalcode FROM importorders) t
```

*91 total, Query took 0.0050 sec*

I then narrowed it to the `country` column on `importcusotmers` and `importorders`

```
SELECT TRIM(country) AS country FROM importcustomers
UNION
SELECT TRIM(shipcountry) AS country FROM importorders
```

```
Argentina
Argentina
Austria
Austria
Belgium
Belgium
...
```

Something interesting happened when I cast the column to `BINARY`

```
SELECT BINARY country AS country FROM importcustomers
UNION
SELECT BINARY shipcountry AS country FROM importorders
```

```
Argentina
417267656e74696e610d
Austria
417573747269610d
Belgium
42656c6769756d0d
...
```

The table `ImportOrders` is causing the duplicates.

```
 SELECT BINARY shipcountry AS country FROM importorders
```

```
4765726d616e790d
5553410d
5553410d
4765726d616e790d
...
```

Looking at the dump you provided, there is an extra `\r` (represented by `0d` in the values) appended to the end of the country.

```
--
-- Dumping data for table `importorders`
--
INSERT INTO `importorders` VALUES 
...'Germany\r'),
...'USA\r'),
...'USA\r'),
...'Germany\r'),
...'Mexico\r'),
```

Where in `importcustomers` the `country` looks fine:

```
--
-- Dumping data for table `importcustomers`
--
INSERT INTO `importcustomers` VALUES 
...'Germany', ... ,
...'Mexico', ... ,
...'Mexico', ... ,
...'UK', ... ,
...'Sweden', ... ,
```

You can remove these `\r`'s (carriage returns) by running this query:

```
UPDATE importorders SET ShipCountry = REPLACE(ShipCountry, '\r', '')
```

You will then get the desired result set if you run your original query. FYI, you do not need the `DISTINCT` if you are using `UNION`.

```
SELECT PostalCode, City, Region, Country
FROM 
    (SELECT postalcode, city, region, country FROM importemployees
    UNION
    SELECT postalcode, city, region, country FROM importcustomers
    UNION
    SELECT postalcode, city, region, country FROM importproducts
    UNION
    SELECT shippostalcode as postalcode, shipcity as city, 
        shipregion as region, shipcountry as country FROM importorders) T
```

Comment: wow. Nice Catch! I noticed the \r in the sqldump myself, but since I'm new to sql it didn't sound any alerts. What sign is \r ? Since it doesn't show up in the GUI? Thanks alot for giving me the "tutorial" too. Another trick learned! :)

EDIT: Testing it out now(removing all \r from sqldump).

Comment: @Graimer the `\r` is a carriage return, which creates a new line. You can read more about it [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/07/01/sql-server-difference-between-line-feed-n-and-carriage-return-r-t-sql-new-line-char/). You can also run a query to remove the `\r`. See my updated answer.

Comment: You Sir, are a genious! :D Been stuck all day. Now I can drop the long insert ignore(and left join ...where .. is null) scripts :D

Comment: @Graimer Glad I could help :) It was a fun challenge!

Comment: You don't need the outer `SELECT` statement, either - it's only effect here is to capitalize the column names, and you could do that equally well by adding `as PostalCode`, etc. to the first `SELECT`.  You also don't need the `as`'s in the last `SELECT`, they have no effect.